# Contents of NSString to plist

Tags: iphone, xcode4, ios4

This is a followup question to what I had asked about "Contents of plist to NSString". How can I get the connects of a NSString shown below into a plist file. What I have read so far by googling is that there is no way to do this without putting the NSString in NSArray/NSdictonary. But the problem is that if I have a NSString with contents shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>a.infoKey</key>
    <array>
        <string>a</string>
        <string>a</string>
        <string>a</string>
        <string></string>
    </array>
    <key>a.titleKey</key>
    <string>a</string>
    <key>r.infoKey</key>
    <array>
        <string>r</string>
        <string>r</string>
        <string>r</string>
        <string></string>
    </array>
    <key>r.titleKey</key>
    <string>r</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

If I add the string above to an NSArray and then create a new plist file, it looks messed up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <string>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;
&lt;!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"&gt;
&lt;plist version="1.0"&gt;
&lt;dict&gt;
    &lt;key&gt;a.infoKey&lt;/key&gt;
    &lt;array&gt;
        &lt;string&gt;a&lt;/string&gt;
        &lt;string&gt;a&lt;/string&gt;
        &lt;string&gt;a&lt;/string&gt;
        &lt;string&gt;&lt;/string&gt;
    &lt;/array&gt;
    &lt;key&gt;a.titleKey&lt;/key&gt;
    &lt;string&gt;a&lt;/string&gt;
    &lt;key&gt;r.infoKey&lt;/key&gt;
    &lt;array&gt;
        &lt;string&gt;r&lt;/string&gt;
        &lt;string&gt;r&lt;/string&gt;
        &lt;string&gt;r&lt;/string&gt;
        &lt;string&gt;&lt;/string&gt;
    &lt;/array&gt;
    &lt;key&gt;r.titleKey&lt;/key&gt;
    &lt;string&gt;r&lt;/string&gt;
&lt;/dict&gt;
&lt;/plist&gt;
</string>
</array>
</plist>
```

I want the exact string (The top one) added to a new plist file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you have is *already* a correctly-formatted plist. If you put that string into another plist object, you'll get what you're seeing, which is an escaped plist-within-a-plist, which isn't what you want.

So what you need to do is simply take your string and save it as a file directly. There are a number of ways to do this, but the simplest way to do it is to use NSString's built-in capability to write itself to a file, like so:

```
[myPlistString writeToFile:somePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

Note that the encoding type should be UTF8. This is what is reflected in the plist string's own header, so that's the encoding type you should be using. (Obviously use the `error` param, too, if you're doing this in production code.)

Once saved to a file (in this case at `somePath`) you don't say what you need to do with it, but you can load it back directly into an object hierarchy by using the `NSPropertyListSerialization` class.

Answer (score 1):

Just save it into a file to a file called `[something].plist` using `-[NSString writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:]`

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked though I just get a warning on compile that writeToFile:atomically is deprecated for NSString. Yet it still works. Thanks again.

Comment: @SamBudda: Use the extra parameters (encoding and error) for both correctness and to avoid the deprecation warning.